# After upgrade to 16.04, Postgresql 9.4 is broken

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

After upgrading, postgresql 9.4 is broken. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The command:

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql start                        (04-29 14:52:01)
[ ok ] Starting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.
The appropriate log entries follow from /var/log/syslog:
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.4-main...
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor postgresql@9.4-main[2390]: Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: postgresql@9.4-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.4-main.
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: postgresql@9.4-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: postgresql@9.4-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 29 14:52:13 igor systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

And, in fact, there is no /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main.
My postgres installation ran just fine on 14.04 before upgrading to 16.04.

Comment: 14.04 runs postgresql 9.3.  Adding the 9.4 version can be done, and the install should put it on the next port (5433), so you can manually dump/insert the date from the 9.3 version and confirm all is working before getting rid of 9.3.  Seems like the 9.4 install did not work.

Answer (score 0):

/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main directory should exist. Try reinstalling postgres. The service require the main directory to be present in the installation directory.